# Ruby on Rails SSL_connect error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I have the following controller- courses-controller.rb:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_term = params[:looking_for] || 'jhu'
    @courses = Coursera.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

Following model - coursera.rb:

```
class Coursera
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
    default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
    format :json

    def self.for term
        get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
    end
end
```

And following view- index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Searching for - <%= @search_term %></h1>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr class=<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %>>
        <td><%= image_tag(course["smallIcon"])%></td>
        <td><%= course["name"] %></td>
        <td><%= course["shortDescription"] %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

But, when I do http://localhost:3000/courses/index, I get the following error:

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed 
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/coursera.rb:9:in `for'
app/controllers/courses_controller.rb:4:in`index'

Please tell me what to do. Nothing works!

Comment: Try changing get("", query: { query: term})["elements"] to get("", query: { query: term, verify: false})["elements"]

Comment: The verify: false skips SSL certification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its complaining that there isn't a valid certificate? If thats the case you can tell HTTParty to ignore the invalid cert for now, like this:

```
class Coursera
    include HTTParty

    default_options.update(verify: false)

...
```

If that works, then you probably want to figure out why it thinks the cert is invalid.

Comment: Yes, this works! Now, why is the cert invalid? From where could I get a valid cert?

Comment: So it is a valid cert,  I don't know enough about your server based on the information given to say how exactly, but you need to add the godaddy cert authority (the cert issuer) to the store on your server that rails is using.  Is this a local VM?

Comment: Yes, it's a local VM.

Comment: See this, set HTTParty's cert authority file to your VM's : http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty%2FClassMethods%3Assl_ca_file

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Mike above would work for you since you are ignoring invalid cert.

Well this might be a workaround to get the thing done. But it's not recommended as you cannot take this code to production.

So it's better to ignore that just for the development env.

Just add the following code block to the end of your `application.rb`
and you should be good to go.

```
if Rails.env.development?
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
> ...
> ```

The certificate contains the following DNS names:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.coursera.org:443 -tls1 -servername api.coursera.org | \
    openssl x509 -text -noout | grep DNS
...
    DNS:*.coursera.org, DNS:coursera.org
```

When you connect to `https://localhost:3000/...`, the certificate must include a DNS name of ***`localhost`***.

Common Names (CN) don't matter. What matters is the Subject Alternate Names (SAN), and they must include all DNS names you user to contact the server.

Also see the following on creating well formed, SSL certificates:

- [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/608639)
- [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639)